# How can I make a screen which has 2 views covering the screen and not overlapping

Tags: ios, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes

I'm trying to create a view controller with 2 views on it which looks just like in the IB [image]

[image]

But they behave this way only on iPhone 5s
In the other cases it looks the way shown on the image in landscape. I use size classes to set the constraints for different screen orientations.

[image]

And this is the way it looks in iPhone 6s plus [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue appeared to be that iPhones earlier than iPhone 6+ have wCompact hCompact size class for landscape. And you should remember not using size classes like wCompact hAny as they will override that compact size class.

So, actually, what you need in this situation is to create 3 size classes:
wCompact hRegular - all portraits 
wCompact hCompact - iPhones earlier than 6+
wRegular hCompact - all the others

Answer (score 1):

Any/Compact means any phone with Compact width, which the iPhones smaller than 6+ are. You need to set the constraints for Regular/Compact to set constraints for iPhones other than 6+ in Portrait.

Comment: I did that but it didn't help((

Comment: What if you remove the constraints on any size class that has Any as width or Any as height? Just the properly defined ones?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is *much* easier with UIStackView.

1. Select your two views.
2. Hit the icon in the lower right to create a UIStackView around them.
3. Set the new UIStackView to be horizontal or vertical by orientation.
4. Pin it to the enclosing view. And you're done!

There's a [good tutorial here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views); I'd strongly recommend you get some practice with setting things up with stack views before doing things the hard way.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about that but I'm concerned by the fact that is available only from iOS 9.0. And 15% of devices run on earlier versions of

Comment: Sounds about right; but how many of that 15% are going to buy your product? For most people, supporting anything other than the current OS isn't worth the extra development/testing/support time. Especially at this point in the cycle where OS 10, or iOS X, or whatever they call it, will be unveiled in the next few weeks...

Comment: Thank you for that) I'll do what you suggested)

Answer (score 0):

You should give constraints like,

`top, bottom, leading and trailing` to both view.

then select both views and give `equal height` constraint and you will get desired result.

you can give it in `any any`. it will work for every orientation.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I need those views to be one under another in portrait  and special deign for iPad so any any won't help((
I do use such constraints but they don't work(((

Comment: It is not mandatory to keep any any. I think this constraints work in every size class. try it.

Comment: the problem is that they just don't work ((
I can send you the source code if you wish

Answer (score 0):

*Add this to the **viewDidLoad** method of your's viewController*

```
UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] init];     
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false;
firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.view addSubview:firstView];
    NSLayoutConstraint *topFirstViewYConstraint = [
```

NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstView                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                          toItem:self.view                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
multiplier:1.0f
constant:0.0f

];

NSLayoutConstraint *centerFirstViewHeightConstraint = [
NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstView
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
toItem:self.view
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
multiplier:0.5f
constant:0.0
   ];

NSLayoutConstraint *centerFirstViewWidthConstraint = [
NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstView
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
toItem:self.view
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth                 multiplier:1.0f                                                          constant:0.0f
   ];
[super.view addConstraints:@[ topFirstViewYConstraint,                                    centerFirstViewHeightConstraint,centerFirstViewWidthConstraint]];

```
UIView *secondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
secondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.view addSubview:secondView];
NSLayoutConstraint *topSecondViewYConstraint = [
```

NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
toItem:firstView
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
multiplier:1.0f
constant:0.0f
   ];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerSecondViewHeightConstraint = [
NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:self.view
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           multiplier:0.5f
constant:0.0
  ];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerSecondViewWidthConstraint = [
NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
toItem:self.view
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
multiplier:1.0f
constant:0.0f
];
    [super.view addConstraints:@[ topSecondViewYConstraint,                                 centerSecondViewHeightConstraint, centerSecondViewWidthConstraint]];